# eager loading not working with order() clause in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, eager-loading

I am using this query to get my data

```
user = User.includes(:skills).order(user: :id)
```

it is working fine. but when i try to display skills by alphabetical order like below

```
user.skills.order(name: :asc)
```

It shows in logs that it goes in the database as `order()` is an `activerecord` method. It seems like `eager loading` is failing here because what's the point to use eager loading if it has to go in the database anyway.

Can anyone guide me what is a good way to do this.

Comment: just as a suggestion, could you please share your logs?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you eager load associated records using `.includes`, you should access the result collection as it is. Otherwise, if you apply more query conditions to the result, it will cause a new DB query. You cannot change the rules in the middle of the game.

There are a few ways how you can order the associated eager loaded records.

**1. Add order condition for the association in the main scope.**

```
user = User.includes(:skills).order("users.id, skills.name ASC")
```

In this case, it won't work like `include` method works by default, making two queries. One query will be performed using 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' to fetch the associated records. This is equivalent to using the `eager_load` method instead of `includes`

```
user = User.eager_load(:skills).order("users.id, skills.name ASC")
```

**2. Add order condition to association when you define it.**

In this case whenever you access the association, the associated records will always be ordered by name.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills, -> { order(:name) }
end
```

**3. Define additional association with required order.**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills_ordered_by_name, -> { order(:name) }, class_name: "Skill"
end
```

Keep in mind that in this case the association should be preloaded and accessed by the defined association name:

```
# preloading the association
users = User.includes(:skills_ordered_by_name)

users.each do |user|
  # accessing the association
  user.skills_ordered_by_name
end
```

**4. Set default order for the associated model.**

This will cause the condition to be applied to every association and query related to the associated model.

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order(:name) }
end
```

**5. Sort eager loaded records using Ruby code (not ActiveRecord query methods)**

This approach is appropriate when there are not many records to sort.

```
users = User.includes(:skills)

users.each do |user|
  # sorting with Ruby's 'sort_by' method
  user.skills.sort_by(&:name)

  # or something like
  user.skills.sort { |one, another| one.name <=> another.name }
end
```

Comment: thanks for detailed answer. but except eager_load nothing worked . why

Comment: Everything should work. What made you think that something does not work: errors, extra DB queries, wrong order or anything else?

Comment: no errors but makes no difference towards result. i implemented these all to check the difference

Comment: If you want, you can publish your code somewhere and give me the link. I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve flexibility by using built-in method [ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader#preload](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb#L85-L96).

It accept three arguments:

```rb
preload(records, associations, preload_scope = nil)
```

The first argument accepts `ActiveRecord::Base` record or array of records.
Second is one or more associations that you want preload to records specified in the first argument.
Last is `Hash` or `Relation` which merged with associations.

Use third argument to get sorted and preloaded associations:

```rb
users = User.order(user: :id)

ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(
  users,
  :skills,
  { order: :name } # or Skill.order(:name)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
user = User.includes(:skills).order(user: :id, name: :desc)
```